# Determining voltage requirement of unknown circuit board

Tags: voltage, vintage

I have a vintage, home-built metal detector from the 50's/60's with a simple circuit board.  It apparently had a home-built battery pack that plugged in but it is now missing (9-volt battery style terminals but spaced far apart).  There is one transformer labeled 6v6/5koms that drives the speaker.  No IC's, all simple components.

I imagine it's either 6v or 9v but I'm curious to know how to determine a best guess.

**update:**
The PP9 battery was what I needed based on the plug.  Thanks also for the suggestions on how to test it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours with the information given.

Comment: Sure, but what information would be used in determining it is the real question.

Comment: A photo of the battery connector may give us a clue. My guess is that it used a 9V PP9 battery, a larger version of the PP3. They were quite common in the 60's and 70's but rare now. Google PP9 battery to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your old circuit and you will probably see lots of electrolytic caps .Note the voltage ratings .Try to find a cap across the supply rail .Now replace the caps.Slowly run the unit up on a lab supply with the volts starting  at zero. Carefully raise the volts while observing the ammeter using the cap voltages as a sensible guide for Vmax. The unit was running of dry cells 1960s so it wont consume lots of current .As a guess it will start running at about 6V and the nominal volts is 9V

Comment: It could likely operate over a wide range of voltages. If the circuitry is just a discrete oscillator, it might function at twice that voltage, but this depends on the transistor used and exact circuit. A photo and any component values would be helpful. I'd say if it starts working at 4v, it's probably 6v-rated. Likewise 7v --> 9v rated. I seem to recall this type of battery connector, but haven't seen one in 30+ years.

Comment: I hadnt heard of a PP9 battery but that looks exactly like what it should be based on the connector and space allowance.  Thank you @Steve G and Autistic for the responses.  I'll see how it works and come back an close the question but I'm pretty sure that nails it.

Answer (score -2):

if you have a bench power supply you could just test it with different voltages starting from low to high.

Comment: How would you determine when to stop increasing the voltage?

Comment: good question, a typical battery for this homemade project shouldn't be more than 12v.  He should stop increasing when its working.

Comment: This is a risky way to address the question.